# error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::less<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const'

Tags: c++, sorting

i wrote a function that will take a vector of points, points is a structure and will sort it using stable sort, i get the following errors:

```
    Error   1   error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::less<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const'
```

that's what my program should do:

```
    in:
    5 8
    3 6
    10 9
    8 11
    7 4
```

and display:

```
    out:
    3 6
    5 8
    7 4
    8 11 
    10 9
```

here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct points
{
    int a, b;

};

int main()
{

    int nbrDeLignes = 0;
    cin >> nbrDeLignes;

    vector<points> tab(nbrDeLignes);
    for (int i = 0; i < nbrDeLignes; i++)
    {
        points p;

        cin >> p.a >> p.b;
        tab.push_back(p);
    }

    //stable_sort(tab.begin(), tab.end());

    for (const points &point : tab)
    {
        cout << point.a << " " << point.b << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

any **HELP** please ;

Comment: Sorting algorithms require an `operator<`, or some other (specified) functor for performing the comparison.

Comment: ty this is it, post as answer so i can upvote you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stable_sort` doesn't know how to sort your `struct` because there is no comparison operator defined for it. You either need to make `points` a `class` and override the `<` operator, or provide `stable_sort` with a comparison function, eg.

```
bool compare_points(point p1, point p2)
{
    return p1.a < p2.a;
}

stable_sort(tab.begin(), tab.end(), compare_points);
```

Comment: You don't actually have to make `points` a `class` in order to override the `<` operator. It works the same way for a `struct` as well.

Comment: Also make your comparison function to take const references as arguments: 
  bool compare_points(const point& p1, const point& p2)

Answer (score 3):

Well, *how* do you want to order your points? How do you know if a point should come before another point when sorted? Do you order by x coordinate, or what? You need to tell the compiler this!

In other words, you need to provide an **operator<**.